# SQLite: How embed the memvfs extension to Amalgamation?

Tags: sqlite, vfs

I need to load/save SQLite database in memory buffer. For this, I want embed the memvfs extension into sqlite3 code and compile it wholly as sqlite3.dll.

How do it?

**Update1:**

I want use the memvfs as temp memory buffer. My program load data from net to buffer, connect to this memory buffer and restore data into empty in-memory db. I thoutgh that inclusion of memvfs to sqlite amalgamation would improve perfomance.

**Update2:**

If you want to use memvfs extension pay attention to bug in readme comment in source. Use "PRAGMA journal_mode=**OFF**" instead "journal_mode=NONE"

**Update3:**

Another bug in memvfs.c - use 'max' instead 'maxsz' for maxsz param in URI.
The sqlite developers carefully set a rakes :(

Comment: Just compile it as a shared library and load it at runtime, or include it directly in your program. Both methods described here: https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html

Comment: I read it. This does not work because extension is loaded in already opened connection to database. How to register memvfs before invoking of sqlite3_open_v2 ?

Comment: You have to load it using a `:memory:` or temp file db first; that should register the vfs so it can be used when opening your real database connection.

Comment: As I know an extension can be registered for connect handle only.  I've tried already create in-memory database, load ext and attach new connection - did not work. And generally, i want include this extension to sqlite library, this way seems faster and further logically. What do you think?

Comment: Worked fine for me when I tested using the open-temp, load module, close-temp, open real using memvfs approach (memvfs is a huge pain to use, though, since you have to copy an existing database file's contents into the memory it uses.). Maybe you should update your post to show the code you're trying to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Test program to demonstrate using memvfs:

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  sqlite3 *db;
  char *err;

  // Open an in-memory database to use as a handle for loading the memvfs extension
  if (sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "open :memory: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  sqlite3_enable_load_extension(db, 1);
  if (sqlite3_load_extension(db, "./memvfs", NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "load extension: %s\n", err);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // Done with this database
  sqlite3_close(db);

  // Read the real database into memory
  int fd = open("foo.db", O_RDONLY);
  if (fd < 0) {
    perror("open");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  struct stat s;
  if (fstat(fd, &s) < 0) {
    perror("fstat");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  void *memdb = sqlite3_malloc64(s.st_size);
  if (read(fd, memdb, s.st_size) != s.st_size) {
    perror("read");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  close(fd);

  // And open that memory with memvfs now that it holds a valid database
  char *memuri = sqlite3_mprintf("file:whatever?ptr=0x%p&sz=%lld&freeonclose=1",
                                 memdb, (long long)s.st_size);
  printf("Trying to open '%s'\n", memuri);
  if (sqlite3_open_v2(memuri, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_URI,
                      "memvfs") != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "open memvfs: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  sqlite3_free(memuri);

  // Try querying the database to show it works.
  sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
  if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT b FROM test", -1, &stmt, NULL) !=
      SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "prepare: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  for (int rc = sqlite3_step(stmt); rc == SQLITE_ROW; rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) {
    printf("%d\n", sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0));
  }

  sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
  sqlite3_close(db);
  return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```sh
# Create a test database to use with memvfs
$ sqlite3 foo.db
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test(b INTEGER);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1), (2);
sqlite> .quit
# Compile the memvfs module and test program
$ gcc -O -fPIC -shared -o memvfs.so memvfs.c
$ gcc -O -Wall -Wextra testmem.c -lsqlite3
# And run it.
$ ./a.out
Trying to open 'file:whatever?ptr=0x56653FE2B940&sz=8192&freeonclose=1'
1
2
```

Same workflow if you compile it directly into your program instead of using a loadable module; you just have to call `sqlite3_memvfs_init()` with the right arguments instead of using `sqlite3_load_extension()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! You have great enlightened me.